# How do I restrict access to the Data Import Wizard but still allow object edit/create in UI?

Tags: data-import, data-import-wizard

I like the new Data Import Wizard, as it is a great tool for power users, but is there any way to limit the use of this tool, aside from the object permissions.

I need my users to have read/write access on certain object, but not the ability to create or edit them en masse using the Data Import Wizard.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Data Import Wizard is governed by a few permissions. See [What permissions do I need to import records?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=faq_import_general_permissions.htm&language=en_US&type=0) for more details, but basically, if you want to restrict *all* access, you can remove the "API Enabled" permission for users. This permission will also prevent users from doing pretty much anything outside of the UI, so you'll have to test it thoroughly.

However, the Data Import Wizard is governed by a bunch of other permissions, such as "Import Personal Contacts", "Modify All Data", "Import Leads", "Import Custom Objects", as well as object permissions. All imports are governed by the user's sharing access as well. So, for example, without "Modify All Data", users could import data to their own records, but not other users'. This is generally as harmless as allowing Inline List Edit, allowing users to update their own data without risking everyone else's.

In summary, just make sure your users' permissions are correct, and they won't be able to do any more damage than they could do manually (if not a bit slower).

Comment: Yeah, that's my primary concern; the last bit. I did read the help page that you linked to, but was hoping that there would be a bit more granularity. I mean, a setting like "Import Custom Objects" seems a bit broad and unrestrictive for Salesforce. There wouldn't be much to stop users from throwing a bunch of dirty data into the system, or creating duplicates if they don't track whether the job succeeds or fails.

Comment: @toolshed there's ways to handle that, such as not giving "create" access to those objects, etc. I agree it's a lot of trouble to get permissions just right, but it's worth the extra effort to do so. Salesforce makes it easy enough to undo most accidents without too much effort, but of course it means you have to assess risk versus benefits. Some knowledgeable power users should be given tools if it saves you time and presents minimal risk.

Comment: Still, it would be nice to cordon off access to only a specific subset of the objects. Sometime the all-or-nothing approach just isn't the right fit. Even a soft measure --such as removing the object from the UI -- would be effective. Appreciate the info.